# Why won't this listener detect window close events?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, windowlistener

I'm trying to listen for events on a single `Frame` via `WindowStateListener`.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;

import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class UserInterface implements WindowStateListener
{
    public static void main(final String[] arguments)
    {
        UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
    }

    public UserInterface()
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Graphics Example");
        frame.addWindowStateListener(this);
        frame.add(new Label("Hello, world!");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println(event.paramString();
    }
}
```

It's working fine for minimization events, but not close events.  [`WINDOW_CLOSING` is definitely a valid `WindowEvent` value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html), and [it's definitely something that `Frame` can throw](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html).  So why isn't it being passed to `windowStateChanged()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WindowStateListeners are not notified of the window closing events. They are only notified of changes to the window's state, such as iconified or de-iconified. If you want close events, implement WindowListener (or extend WindowAdapter). This tutorial explains it http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
{
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEv)

}}
```

---

> this would definitely compiled.

```
class TestSnippet {
    public static void main(Sring[] args) {

        // START: copy/pasted snippet
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
        {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEv)

        }}
        // END: copy/pasted snippet
    }
}
```

(A passerby notes) Well, except for..

```
I:\proj\TestSnippet.java:7: ';' expected
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEv)
                                                    ^
I:\proj\TestSnippet.java:9: ')' expected
        }}
         ^
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: this would definitely compiled.In this listener we can perform the task which we have to do when we are closing the window.

Comment: Ok now i understand that what were you trying to say.Ya thats write.

Comment: Feel free to edit out my additions.  But please correct the snippet (or make it even more general) at the same time.  +1 for the pointer to `WindowListener`.